# How to use the if / else conditions when opening a file. Python

Tags: python

Is there any way to use conditions when opening a file?
Example: when you finish reading all the lines, `print ("Reading finished")`

```
 with open("read.txt", "r") as s:
        for lines in s:
            data = lines.split(":")
            e = data[0]
            m = data[1]
            #When I finished reading all the lines
            print("Read Finish")
```

I can't find any answer on the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

Drop out of your `for` loop.

```
with open("read.txt", "r") as s:
    for lines in s:
        data = lines.split(":")
        e = data[0]
        m = data[1]
    #When I finished reading all the lines
    print("Read Finish")
```